# Parallel missForest

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

In the following example I am trying to use missForest to impute missing values. To speed up the process I used foreach package. In which i used  100 trees then I passed those trees to missForest function.   Is this the right way to parallel missForest?

Here is example and what I have done:

```
   library(foreach)
   library(missForest)
   data(iris)
   iris.na <- iris
   set.seed(111)

   ## artificially drop some data values.

   for (i in 1:4) iris.na[sample(150, sample(20)), i] <- NA
    set.seed(222)

     system.time(rf <- foreach(ntree=100, .combine=combine, 
    .multicombine=TRUE,.packages='missForest') %dopar% 
    { missForest(iris.na)$ximp})
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this should solve your problem.

```
library(doParallel)
library(missForest)
data(iris)
iris.na <- iris
set.seed(111)

## artificially drop some data values.

for (i in 1:4) iris.na[sample(150, sample(20)), i] <- NA
set.seed(222)

registerDoParallel(cores=3)
out <- missForest(iris.na, ntree = 100, parallelize = "forests")
```

Answer (score 1):

In looking over the code for missForest, I don't see a way to parallelize a single call to it without modifying the missForest function itself.  You could certainly make multiple calls to it in parallel, but that doesn't seem to be what you want to do.

Some additional notes on your example code:

- The foreach loop uses only a single iteration.
- The `ntree` variable is not used.
- Since `missForest(iris.na)$ximp` returns a data frame, you shouldn't combine the results with the `combine` function which requires randomForest objects.
- No parallel backend is registered.

Comment: @hema Are you asking how exactly to modify missForest to execute randomForest in parallel?

Comment: yes, please if you can ---- i saw that question several times and never good answer.

Comment: @hema I attempted to show you how to parallelize missForest in another question that you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20225809/2109128